# Configuring IDE for Nosetests for python: How do I get script option?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, nose

My friend has following setup with his Nose tests.  Basically, he sees "Script" option for test but I do not. 
IDE information Pycharm CE:2017.2

[Friend setup with test/script option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yonnA.png) 
[image]

My set up is as follows. 
[My Setup without test option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffq1w.png)
[image]

Question: How do I get "test" instead of target and "Script" instead of python/path/custom.

Comment: You should have pointed out that your question is not about nose itself but about your IDE setup.

Comment: @SherylHohman, The user is a new user. For them, stackoverflow, doesn't allow image embedding. It shows only link to imgur.

Comment: @KlausD. edited title

Comment: You still missed the most important part: your IDE and the version(s) used.

Comment: @user763410 gotcha.  I'll remove comment, and add images as an edit.

Comment: Thanks, I updated both Pycharm IDE version and tag.